# Multi column forms with fieldsets

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

<sup><sub>Sorry for the vague title, I wasn't sure how to describe it better.</sub></sup>
I'm currently upgrading a website to bootstrap 3 and got a little problem with multiple inputs in one form row.

In bootstrap 2, I would have simply created two `.controls.controls-row` with `.spanX` elements inside to create the necessary columns.
However, as these are removed in bootstrap 3, I replaced them with `.form-group` and the new column classes.

If I have two rows inside the form (resp. fieldset in this case), the first one becomes non-editable if the second one is a one-column row (see code and attached screenshot below).

I inspected the elements with firebug and saw that the `.col-sm-12` from the second fieldset lays over the `.form-group` and does not let the user click the elements inside.
In the first fieldset with the `.col-sm-12` first, everything works fine.

I also tried placing a `.row` around each `.form-group` which solves the issue, but increases the width of the form line, so it does no longer has a left margin inside the fieldset.

Is there a way to solve this without increasing the form-row width?

EDIT: I added the generated code as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/)

```
%fieldset
  %legend= t('.login_information')
  .form-group
    .col-sm-12
      = f.label :login
      = f.text_field :login, :class => 'form-control', :required => true

  .form-group
    .col-sm-6
      = f.label :password
      = f.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      = f.label :password_confirmation
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'form-control'

%fieldset
  %legend= t('.personal_details')
  .form-group
    .col-sm-4
      = f.label :title
      = f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control'
    .col-sm-4
      = f.label :firstname
      = f.text_field :firstname, :class => 'form-control', :required => true
    .col-sm-4
      = f.label :lastname
      = f.text_field :lastname,  :class => 'form-control', :required => true

  .form-group
    .col-sm-12
      = f.label :email
      = f.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control email', :required => true
```

[image: Non-editable form elements]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to be adjusted in your layout:

1. You are nesting `col` elements within `form-group` elements. This should be the other way around (the `form-group` should be within the `col-sm-xx` element).
2. You should always use a `row` div for each new "row" in your design. In your case, you would need at least 5 rows (Username, Password and co, Title/First/Last name, email, Language). Otherwise, your problematic `.col-sm-12` is still on the same row with the above 3 `.col-sm-4` resulting in a total of columns greater than 12, and causing the overlap problem.

Here is a fixed [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/2/).

And an excerpt of what the problematic section HTML should become:

```xml
<fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>    
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for="user_title">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="user_title" name="user[title]" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for="user_firstname">First name</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="user_firstname" name="user[firstname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for="user_lastname">Last name</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="user_lastname" name="user[lastname]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <div class='form-group'>

                <label for="user_email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control required email" id="user_email" name="user[email]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted `.form-group` as a replacement for the old `.control-group` instead of just grouping an element with possible addons. About the rows: That's what I thought, but this removes the padding for the elements within the fieldset. I guess I'll have to add it myself.

Comment: @stex instead of adding the padding yourself, wrap all your code with a Bootstrap 3 `.container` div. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/3/).

Comment: I meant the padding for form fields inside the fieldset as in my [original code](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/). I can, however, place a container inside of each fieldset in the form to get the desired padding, but I'm not sure if that's how the container class should be used

Comment: Ah I see. You are right, you should probably add this yourself with custom containers.

Comment: I'm using <div class="form-group col-XX-XX ...> Is there any inconsistency with this approach?

Comment: Bootstrap docs specifically say that form-group replaces row in horizontal forms.

"Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the form. Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row."

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

As such, they shouldn't be embedded within col-*-* unless you're going to then have further embedded col-*-* divs within them. In other words @Gilbertoca, don't do that.

Comment: This way you cannot adjust the labels and inputs (giving them each a size like col-md-4 for label and col-md-8 for input) unless you create another row and columns inside the form-group which kinda beats the purpose. Based on bootstrap documentation @OregonJeff answer is the proper way of doing this and it should work properly.

Answer (score 15):

I disagree that .form-group should be within .col-*-*n* elements. In my experience, all the appropriate padding happens automatically when you use .form-group like .row within a form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="user_login">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="user_login" name="user[login]" required="true" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/62/).

Altering the demo slightly by adding .form-horizontal to the form tag changes some of that padding.

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/63/).

When in doubt, inspect in Chrome or use Firebug in Firefox to figure out things like padding and margins. Using .row within the form fails in edsioufi's fiddle because .row uses negative left and right margins thereby drawing the horizontal bounds of the divs classed .row beyond the bounds of the containing fieldsets.

Comment: Yeah, but your method produces inconsistent vertical spacing.  The "Email" label is flush against the "Title" input while "Password" is 59px from the "Username" input.

Comment: I think the problem is that the labels are missing space above them in XS mode.

Comment: The problem is caused by form-group not appropriately clearing the col-sm-* floats. Adding "clearfix" class to the div with "form-group" class fixes it. See the following demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/352/.

Comment: `.form-group` acts as row only when you specify `form-horizontal` [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: It isn't a matter of opinion as your answer would suggest. Using `col-*` inside of `form-group` causes no margin on the bottom. Yes, `clearfix` handles the issue, but that seems like a workaround.

Comment: When the validation happens it adds the has-error class to div which has .form-group class so all the row becomes red which is not expected