# nested_attributes with simple_field_for getting unpermitted parameters error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have models

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :user_interests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_interests
end

class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :interest
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :profiles, :through => :user_interests
end
```

`controller`

```
private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, user_interests_attributes: {:interest => []})
    end
```

view

```
=#"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428871/multi-column-forms-with-fieldsets"
= simple_form_for(@profile, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
  .well.well-lg
    %fieldset
      %legend Personal Information
      .row
        .col-sm-4
          .form-group
            = f.input :first_name, label: 'First Name*'
            = f.hint 'No special characters, please!'
        .col-sm-4
          .form-group
            = f.input :last_name, label: 'First Name*'
            = f.hint 'No special characters, please!'
      .row
        .col-sm-4
          .form-group
            = f.input :date_of_birth, as: :string, 'data-behaviour'=>'datepicker'
      %legend Other Information
      .row
        .col-sm-4
          .form-group
            = f.simple_fields_for :user_interests, UserInterest.new do |s|
              = s.collection_select(:interest, Interest.all, :id, :name,{},{:multiple=>true})
            = f.hint 'Please use Ctrl key on your keyboard to select multiple items'
      .row
        = f.submit
```

But getting error unpermitted parameters

> profile_params
>
> Unpermitted parameters: interest
>
> => {"first_name"=>"",  "last_name"=>"",  "date_of_birth"=>"",  "user_interests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{}}}

where my params are:

> params
> => {"utf8"=>"✓",  "_method"=>"patch",  "authenticity_token"=>"7/7sKljbi88cmUOen/WFWzhzV6exE8I8fBnNMA5EELw=",
> "profile"=>   {"first_name"=>"",    "last_name"=>"",
> "date_of_birth"=>"",
> "user_interests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"interest"=>"test"}}},
> "commit"=>"Update Profile",  "action"=>"update",
> "controller"=>"profiles",  "id"=>"1"}

Please correct me where I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :interest` on UserInterest.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :user_interests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_interests
end

class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :interest
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interest
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :profiles, :through => :user_interests
end
```

You might have to define interest as a valid parameter on strong_parameters definition in your controller.